# Linq Expression works on Desktop but errors on Server

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

This is the strangest thing I've ever seen, but hopefully someone else has because I am clueless.  I have the following code:

```
 DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        List<InvoiceItem> itemList = new List<InvoiceItem>();
        int listSize = 30;
        int listIndex = 0;
        try
        {
            itemList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                        select new InvoiceItem()
                        {
                            CustomerRef = dr["CustomerRef"].ToString(),
                            Description = dr["Description"].ToString(),
                            ItemRef = dr["ItemRef"].ToString(),
                            Rate = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Rate"].ToString()),
                            Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Quantity"].ToString()),
                            PONumber = dr["PONumber"].ToString(),
                            UnitOfMeasure = dr["UnitOfMeasure"].ToString(),
                            RefNumber = dr["RefNumber"].ToString(),
                            Total = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Total"].ToString()),
                            Address1 = dr["Address1"].ToString(),
                            Address2 = dr["Address2"].ToString(),
                            Address3 = dr["Address3"].ToString(),
                            Address4 = dr["Address4"].ToString(),
                            City = dr["City"].ToString(),
                            State = dr["State"].ToString(),
                            PostalCode = dr["PostalCode"].ToString(),
                            ServiceDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["ServiceDate"].ToString()) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(dr["ServiceDate"].ToString()),
                            TxnDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["TxnDate"].ToString()) ? DateTime.Now : DateTime.Parse(dr["TxnDate"].ToString()),
                            Note = dr["Note"].ToString()



                        }).ToList();

            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list = loadItems();
            List<InvoiceItem> createNewItemsList = new List<InvoiceItem>();
            foreach (var importing in itemList)
            {
                var matchingvalues = list.Where(l => l.Contains(importing.ItemRef));
                //If there is no match in Quickbooks already...
                if (matchingvalues.Count() < 1)
                {
                    createNewItemsList.Add(new InvoiceItem
                    {
                        ItemRef = importing.ItemRef,
                        UnitOfMeasure = importing.UnitOfMeasure
                    });
                }
            }
```

Here is the Code for loadItems():

```
        private List<string> loadItems()
    {
        string request = "ItemQueryRq";
        connectToQB();
        int count = getCount(request);
        IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.processRequestFromQB(BuildItemQuery());
        string[] itemList = parseItemQueryRs(responseMsgSet, count);

        disconnectFromQB();
        List<string> list = new List<string>(itemList);
        return list;
    }
```

Here is a view of the error:

[image]

here shows list count:

[image]

When I run this code on my deskotp, if **matchingvalues.Count() = 0** it executes the code correctly.  However, when I run the exact same code in debug on the server, that line of code errors out with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  Can anybody explain why this might happen and if there is any work around for it?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. Are you sure that you are using the exact same data source locally and on the server? What does `loadItems()` do? Can you include the code for that just in case?

Comment: EXACTLY the same.  And the thing is, list = loadItems() returns 28 records.  So I'm baffled here.  It errors out on Count().  I put in int test = matchinvalues.Count() and get the error.

Comment: Which object is `null`, `matchingvalues` or something else? The `matchingvalues` is lazy-loaded when you call `.Count()` on it, so it's not doing the `.Where` filtering until you try to `.Count()` them. The source of the exception you got will be the biggest clue.

Comment: I'm importing the exact same Excel spreadhseet and comparing with the exact same Company file.  The only difference is the versions of Quickbooks.  One is Quickbooks Pro, and one is Quickbooks Premier, otherwise, same data  files.

Comment: I see your new image. Only thing I can think of is `importing` is null and it blew during iteration. Perhaps check that and paste the stacktrace? Actually, `ItemRef` might be null as Contains will throw a null reference exception when you pass in null: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You would think that, but importing is not null.  I can hover and read the string.

Comment: `matchingvalues` clearly shows as null there, and you're doing a `.Count()` on that. That's what throws..

Comment: @FredKleuver We get that, but trying to figure out how that is even possible and what is causing it. Based on code it should just be an IEnumerable that either iterates 0 or more items.

Comment: It seems OK in my opinion as well. If the server is not Windows(.NET), it can be a bug of Mono.

Comment: The underlying query that is called by `loadItems()` is choking somewhere. The `.where` expression doesn't throw because it doesn't immediately execute the query, but the `.count()` will. Can you show the code in `loadItems()`?

Comment: You're also talking about different versions of QuickBooks. Could be a configuration or state problem in the installation or userprofile that doesn't allow you to load the file.

Comment: loadItems() returns 27 records.The Quickbooks files is loaded and returns 27 records.  By the time it gets to the code above, Quickbooks should be out of the mix.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the `.where` expression as a `foreach` loop? `var matchingvalues = new List<string>()`, then loop through the list, check for `.Contains` and add value to the list if it matches. Might expose what's going on.

Comment: I'm working on iterating both list with foreach loop. now.

Comment: Side note, you could rewrite your if check to this: `if (!list.Any(l => l.Contains(importing.ItemRef)))`, but that's for after this issue is solved I suppose..